# find elements that both exist in two arrays

Tags: php

I have two arrays like the following:

Array1

```
Array ( [price] => 117.00 [recurring_profile] => [use_config_gift_message_available] => 1 [stock_data] => Array ( [use_config_manage_stock] => 1 [original_inventory_qty] => 100 [qty] => 100 [use_config_min_qty] => 1 [use_config_min_sale_qty] => 1 [use_config_max_sale_qty] => 1 [is_qty_decimal] => 0 [is_decimal_divided] => 0 [use_config_backorders] => 1 [use_config_notify_stock_qty] => 1 [use_config_enable_qty_increments] => 1 [use_config_qty_increments] => 1 [is_in_stock] => 1 ) [website_ids] => Array ( [0] => 1 ) [can_save_configurable_attributes] => [can_save_custom_options] => [can_save_bundle_selections] => [type_has_options] => [type_has_required_options] => )
```

Array2

```
Array ( [price] => 118.0000 )
```

I use

```
$newarr =array_intersect_assoc($oldValues, $newValues);
```

but `$newarr` will be blank, any ideas?

My expected results:

`$newArray1 = Array ( [price] => 117.00 );`

Comment: What result are you expecting from running your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's blank, because price has different values 117.00 and 118.0000

You can try array_intersect_key

Answer (score 0):

array_intersect_assoc() will only return items where BOTH the key and value match.